# Can I automatically export data from a Cognos report into a database?

Tags: database, excel, tableau-api, cognos

The overall goal is to have data from an automated daily Cognos report stored in a database so that I am able to report not only on that day but also historical data if I so choose. My general thought is that if I can find a way to automatically add the new daily data to an existing Excel file, I can then use that as my data source and create a dashboard in Tableau. However, I don't have any programming experience, so I'm floundering here.

I'm committed to using Tableau, but I chose Excel only because I'm more familiar with that program than others, along with the fact that an Excel output file is an option in Cognos. If you have better ideas, please don't hesitate to suggest them along with why you believe it's a better idea.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this without manually downloading your report from Cognos.  Once you have that, you can use any number of tools to automate importing that to SQL for use in Tableau.

Comment: Sounds like you're spending most of your time copying data from one tool to another. Cognos is simply reporting data it retrieves from a database. I'd try to get access to query the original if possible, and just cut out the middleman.

Comment: @durbnpoisn So if I had Cognos automatically save an Excel file of that day's data, then I could use a macro to append it to a separate Excel file, then pull it into Tableau? That seems like it would work even if it's a little clunky.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore That make more sense but I'm not sure where the original is. That's a me problem though, not a system problem.

Thank you both for your help!

Comment: If you have access to Visual Studio with BIDS, you can write a package to automate the whole thing.  Then use SQL Server Management Studio to run the job automatically.  At that point, the process of getting all of your data into SQL is there, and you can use Tableua to run your reports.

Comment: Shannon, What I meant was that Cognos is reading from a database, say an Oracle database. So the ideal world is to skip Cognos altogether and point Tableau at the original Oracle database. No excel files at all. Lots of time people don't want to give you access because then you wouldn't need the unnecessary Cognos layer which is what provides their income. But if you can get a read only connection to the database, that can simplify things.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Right, I just don't think I'll be granted access to that database. I'm looking into it, but I work at a large company and our EDM department tends towards being conservative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this an an answer because, it's just too much to leave as a comment.

What you need are 3 things.

1. Figure out how to have COGNOS run your report and download your Excel file.
2. Use Visual Studio with BIDS (which is the suite of SQL analysis, reporting,  and integration services) to automate all the stuff you need to do to append your Excel files, etc...  Then you can use the same tools to import that data to your SQL server.

   - In fact, if all you're doing is trying to get this data into SQL, you can skip the Append Excel part, and just append the data directly to your SQL table.
   - Once your package is built, you can save it as an automated job on your SQL server to run whenever you wish.
3. Tableau can use your SQL server as a data source.  Once you have that updated, you can run your reports.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I'm still jumping through hoops to try to get read-only access to the backend database to make this process a lot more efficient, but in the meantime I've moved forward with the long method utilizing Cognos.

I was able to leverage a coworker to create a system file folder to automatically save the Cognos reports to, and then I scheduled a job to run the reports I need. Each of those now saves into a folder in a shared network drive (so my entire team has access to the files), and I wrote a series of macros to append the data each day from those feeder files in the shared drive to a Master File. Now all that's left is to create a Tableau dashboard using the Master File as the data source and I'll have what I need.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: "I was able to leverage a coworker to create a system file folder to automatically save the Cognos reports to" - I realize this question is old but did this coworker have higher permissions than you to access admin tools in order to create this?